# Character const or string const?

Tags: c++

Here is a part of the code that seeks to display the names of people that have blood group as `a+` or `ab+`.

```
//class definition
class bloodbank
{
   int idno;
   char doname[30];
   char group[3];

   //the function i am talking about   
   void blood()
   {
       bloodbank b;
       int count =0;
       ifstream fin("donor.dat",ios::binary);
       if( (strcmp(b.retgroup(),'A+')==0) ||(strcmp(b.retgroup(),'AB+')==0 )   )
       {
           b.display();
           count++;
           fin.read((char*)&b,sizeof(b));
       }
       fin.close();
       cout<<"No of records"<<" "<<count;
   }
}
```

i am confused whether i have to put "A+" or just 'A+'.

if i put "A+", i get count as 0.

Comment: 'AB+' is not a string, it's supposed to be a character. If you want a string, use "AB+2. But you are in C++, use string.

Comment: 1) "_i am confused whether i have to put "A+" or just 'A+'._" If it's a single character - use single quotes, if it's a sequence of characters - use double quotes. Since `A+` is not a single character, the solution seems obvious. 2) "_if i put "A+", i get count as 0._" Then, there's problem in your algorithm, did you step through your code with a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

`'A+'` is a *multicharacter literal* in C++. It has an `int` type, but the value is *implementation-defined*, although `'A' * 256 + '+'` is common.

As such they are rarely used.

You want `"A+"`. That is a `const char[3]` type that *decays* to a `const char*` pointer which `strcmp` can use.

Finally, you're using C++. Why not use `std::string` rather than those `char[]` types? Then you could write `b.retgroup() == "A+"` and so on rather than those `strcmp` calls. Or if you need to retain the `char[]` for some reason, you could use, from C++14 onwards, the flashy *Yoda-expression*

```
"A+"s == b.retgroup()
```